# Problems with the usage of Belief and Common Belief operators

Tags: elementary-set-theory, modal-logic

I have a problem with the usage of a Belief operator $B_i$ in the derivation of a result on a common belief operator $CB$.

First of all, some basic definitions (where $i$ is an individual), that will be useful:
$E = \prod_i E_i$
$E_{-i} = \prod_{j \neq i} E_i$
$B(E) = \prod_i B_i (E_{-i})$
$B^k (E) = B ( B^{k-1} (E)) \text{ with }k>1$
$CB (E) = \bigcap_{k \geq 1} B^k (E)$

Here there is my problem.

$$\begin{align} CB (E) = \bigcap_{k \geq 1} B^k (E) & = B(E) \cap \bigcap _{k\geq2} B^k (E)=\\
& = \prod_i B_i (E_{-i}) \cap \bigcap_{k \geq 2} B^k (E) = \\
& = \prod_i B_i (E_{-i}) \cap \bigcap_{k \geq 2} B (B^{k-1} (E)) = \\
& = \prod_i B_i (E_{-i}) \cap \bigcap_{k \geq 2} \prod_i B_i (B_{-i}^{k-1} (E)) = \\
& = \prod_i \left( B_i (E_{-i}) \cap \bigcap _{k \geq 2} B_i (B_{-i}^{k-1} (E)) \right) \equiv \prod_i CB_i (E)
\end{align}$$

My problem is with what the last step does not make explicit. My guess is that this is the following

$$\begin{align} \prod_i \left( B_i (E_{-i}) \cap \bigcap _{k \geq 2} B_i (B_{-i}^{k-1} (E)) \right) & = \prod_i \left( B_i (E_{-i}) \cap \bigcap _{k \geq 2} B_{i}^k (E) \right) = \\
& = \prod_i \bigcap_{k \geq 1} B^{k}_{i} (E_{-i})
\end{align}$$

However, assuming my guess is correct, there are two things I don't see completely:
1) the relation between $B$ and $B^{k-1}$ in presence of an index $i$;
2) the logic behind the presence of both $E$ and $E_{-i}$, and how they end up in $\prod_i CB_i (E)$.

Thanks a lot for any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the last step is definitional (hence the $\equiv$ symbol); in other words, the formula inside the parentheses is the *definition* of $CB_{i}(E)$.

Of course, this still leaves open the question of what the heck $B_{-i}^{k-1}(E)$ is. Going by the equality between the 3rd and 4th line, it seems like it is just an abbreviation for
$$(B^{k-1}(E))_{-i} = \prod_{j \neq i} B_{j}(B_{-i}^{k-2}(E)).$$
The real source of confusion here then might actually be the definition of $B(E)$. Usually this is read "everyone believes $E$", but the formulation you provided says something apparently weaker, namely that each agent $i$ believes $E_{-i}$. Why is this? I'm not sure—I'd need to look at the paper you took this from—but my guess is that $E = \prod_{i} E_{i}$ is assumed to be such that each $E_{i}$ is something that $i$ is sure of (i.e. something that satisfies $B_{i}(E_{i}) \leftrightarrow E_{i}$); for example, $E_{i}$ could be an action that $i$ is choosing to take, or (assuming introspection) a belief that $i$ has about some other event.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answer: I read it only now. About the content of your answer, I do not really agree on the notation you used neither for $(B^{k-1} (E))_{-i}$, nor for the subsequent formula, where using $j$ seems slightly redundant (usally $j$ stands for $-i$ when there are two agents). Morevore, I think we actually know what $B^{k-1}_{-i} (E)$ is.